# DOM prototype chain traversal in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome

Chrome gives follwing prototype chain for a div:

```
element = document.getElementById("test")
<div id=​"test">​…​</div>​
element.__proto__
HTMLDivElement
element.__proto__.__proto__
HTMLElement
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
Element
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
Node
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
Object
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
null
```

While in case of Firefox i get something like below and xpconnect looks like some bridge.
I got same prototype chain picture in Mozilla documentation (same as Chrome). here my question is how to get Node object by traversing from HTMLDiv element ? Can someone write js code that gives me Node object or any other object like HTMLElement if we have div element?

Image looks same as chrome model but i need code to traverse this tree :)

Thanks in advance.

[Link of image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript-DOM_Prototypes_in_Mozilla)

[image]

```
var element = document.getElementById("test");
element.toString();
[object HTMLDivElement]
element.__proto__.toString();
[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]
element.__proto__.__proto__.toString();
[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.toString();
[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.toString();
[object DOM Constructor.prototype]
element.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.toString();
[object Object]
```

I believe element.constructor.prototype.**proto** and element.**proto** is same thing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to compare properties of chrome and firefox at each step of chain.

Comment: There's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684601) in Firefox that causes `toString` to return `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]`.

Answer (score -1):

a object's **proto** is a object , which of course have a **proto** ref to a object, so they all the same